# Can't enter to BIOS after debian install only black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, grub-efi

I have Acer Aspire laptop with windows 10. recently I installed Debian 9 in a different partition and everything went fine. The second time I tried to boot into bios I only have a black screen with a dash on it.

Also I can't boot grub because windows boot manager boots first (this is why I want to enter the bios).

Windows 10 boots just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, but I do believe that the boot loader and/or the boot manager does not affect accessing the BIOS Setup. Have you tried other key combinations to access the BIOS Setup?

If you want to boot into Debian, boot into Windows 10 and:

1. Press the `Windows Key + R` to open the Run Box
2. Type `msconfig.msc` and hit `Enter`
3. Navigate to the `Boot` tab

In this tab you should be able to choose what IS to boot into if Windows is aware of the dual boot configuration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i've tried every key from f1 to f12 and del but nothing happend it's always the black screen. in msconfig i can't find debian boot